# Javascript adapter for Tibco EMS

Tags: message-queue, javascript, tibco-ems

I'm working on a project requiring a fast time to market, so we're considering using a web ui rather than building something heavier.

My query is because I'm in search of a javascript library for Tibco EMS. I've seen similar for ActiveMQ I believe, but our infrastructure already uses EMS.

Would anybody have an idea about how to consume messages from EMS via Javascript?

Thanks,

Faheem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know EMS does not have a RESTful interface so you're not going to be able to access it directly. There are also security issue with trying to do that.

The way around it is to create an AJAX / REST Server page in, asp.net or java that will be the proxy, and call EMS on behalf of your page.